# Does Hazelcast follow JSR-107

Tags: hazelcast

Read about JSR-107 and JCache recently. 
Would like to know whether Hazelcast or Ehcache follow this JSR?

Answer (score 7):

JSR107 (JCache) made good progress and we already notified the spec committee that Hazelcast will implement the JCache spec. Having JCache part of Java EE 8 will be significant achievement so Hazelcast is now committed to JCache.

-talip (hazelcast founder)

Answer (score 4):

As far as Hazelcast goes, here is a response from [Talip Ozturk](http://www.hazelcast.com/company.jsp):

> > 1. Does hazelcast have any plans to support JSR107? If so, any release date?
>   It shouldn't be hard to support JSR107 but it is a 10 years old JSR
>   that is never been finalized. We don't want to spend time on it until
>   we see an official release of the spec.

*Found on [this page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/tF27kaxg18s).*

As far as Ehcache goes, here is a possible implementation that may work: https://github.com/jsr107/ehcache-jcache

Answer (score 4):

Hazelcast 3.3.1 passed the JSR107 final TCK and was accepted by the JCP as compatible. Makes sense since the JCache spec co-author is the CEO of Hazelcast

You can download it at http://hazelcast.org/download

Answer (score 0):

If you need an implementation of JCache, the only one that I'm aware of being available today is Oracle Coherence; see: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/jcache_part.htm

*For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the opinions or views of my employer.*

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast is now fully complied with Jsr107 or Jcache. This is announced in the official [Blog](http://blog.hazelcast.com/2014/09/29/jcache-supercomputing-for-the-rest-of-us/)

> > > On the opening day of JavaOne and Oracle Open World, Hazelcast, the leading In-Memory Data Grid provider is announcing the release of Hazelcast 3.3.1 JCache, the JCache compatible version of Hazelcast.

And acording to [this](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-documentation/src/JCache.md)

> > > Hazelcast JCache implementation is 100% TCK (Technology Compatibility Kit) compliant and therefore passes all specification requirements.
> > >       The samples in hazel cast makes it somewhat easy to learn jcache as there is really poor JavaDocs and other resources